# Не отображаются данные в приложении HubApp XAML/C#

Tags: c#, json, xaml

Я взял за основу Hub приложение и несколько изменил его. Я создал свой JSON с данными, слегка подкорректировал `SampleDataSource.cs` для корректной работы. Всё вроде хорошо, но, когда я дошёл до подключения данных к странице, у меня возникли проблемы. Я подключаю `d:DataContext`, пишу в нём корректные данные, которые сразу же появляются на экране во `ViewPort`'e, однако при развёртывании приложения данных нет - пусто. В `DataContext` я забиндил ту переменную, которую получил в классе страницы из `SampleDataSource`. Могли бы подсказать, в чём проблема? В интернете я ничего не нашёл, и промучился с этой ерундой почти 2 дня.

Код страницы:
Ресурс:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Standard310-260ItemTemplate">
        <Grid Height="250" Width="310" Margin="5,10,5,10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="150">
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" MaxHeight="60" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

...

<HubSection IsHeaderInteractive="True" DataContext="{Binding SubjectsA}"
            d:DataContext="{Binding Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/SubjectSource.json, Type=data:SampleDataSource}}"
            Header="Предметы" Padding="40,40,40,32">
            <DataTemplate>
                <GridView
                    x:Name="itemGridView"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Subjects}"
                    Margin="-9,-14,0,0"
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Items In Group"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard310-260ItemTemplate}"
                    SelectionMode="None"
                    IsSwipeEnabled="false"
                    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                    ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
                </GridView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
```

DataContext для всей страницы:

```
        DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

А вообще, это стандартный Hub, просто немного переделанный. Subjects - это массив из JSON, а SubjectsA - это из HubPage.cs:

```
        private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();
        public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel
        {
            get { return this.defaultViewModel; }
        }
        ...
        var sampleDataGroup = await SampleDataSource.GetGroupsAsync();
        DefaultViewModel["SubjectsA"] = sampleDataGroup;`
```

Поставил точку останова на последнюю строчку, всё правильно - для `sampleDataGroup` присвоены корректные, нужные мне значения. Только в развёрнутом приложении они почему-то не отображаются.

Или, может, HubApp написан именнно под отображение Item'ов, а не Group?

Класс SampleDataSource, который отвечает за получение из JSON, слишком громоздкий и выкладывать его долго. Но я там мало что изменил, а так он дефолтный от HubApp.

Comment: Сложно угадать, что именно неправильно, не имея кода. Покажите ваш код. Например, интересно, где и как вы устанавливаете `DataContext`.

Comment: Окей, а где вы устанавливаете `DataContext` всей странице? И что такое `DefaultViewModel`?